# how to solve "No module named crypto error

Tags: python, firebase, kivy

I am trying to use the authentication feature in firebase for email and password/. i have the following code:

```
import pyrebase

firebaseConfig = {
  'apiKey': "AIzaSyDO80bIZpwVVTS2vpAzRiKBpha9nCIIHpg",
  'authDomain': "kintil-s-project2.firebaseapp.com",
  'databaseURL': "https://kintil-s-project2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  'projectId': "kintil-s-project2",
  'storageBucket': "kintil-s-project2.appspot.com",
  'messagingSenderId': "55270635464",
  'appId': "1:55270635464:web:e283b8301ead1df396f2fd",
  'measurementId': "G-WP9GZWXVBX"
```

}

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)

Auth = firebase.auth()

email = input('enter email')
password = input('enter password')

#Auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
```

when i ran the above, i got the following error:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

what can i do to solve this problem.

PS i was having issue installing pycrytodome from cmd using pip, so i installed from pycharm.

Comment: are you executing your program from pycharm using the same python version where you installed Crypo?

Comment: @ Sembei Norimaki yes

Comment: What was the issue you had been having while trying to install pycryptodome?

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki  the issue actually started when i tried to install pyrebase from cmd, it was having issue installing pycryptodome. the installation stopped at pycrytodome. so i tried to installed only pycryptodome  from cmd and got the same installation issue. that was why i installed pyrebase from pycharm. here is the error i got while trying to install pycryptodome from cmd: 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycryptodome
  Running setup.py clean for pycryptodome
Failed to build pycryptodome

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a problem with `pycryptodome` module while installing it with pip, so without the `pycryptodome` module `pyrebase` will not work properly. But there is good alternative for `pyrebase`, that is `firebase-admin` module by Google and it works like a charm with almost similar functionalities. It is very easy to switch to the `firebase-admin` module and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python) are the official docs of Firebase Admin Python SDK.

### For your requirement here is the complete code,

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth

"""  To get the your service.json file, follow these steps
    1) Go to your firebase console and login
    2) Click on the Gear(settings) icon beside Poject Overview
    3) Then go to, Project Settings -> Service Accounts -> Click Generate new private key
    4) Your service.json file will be downloaded, added it to your main.py file directory
"""

# Initializing the firebase-admin
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/your/service.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

# Taking the email and password from user
your_email = input('enter email')
your_password = input('enter password')

# Creating the user with email and password
user = auth.create_user(email= your_email, password= your_password)
print(user.uid)
```

### Edit

For more information visit the official [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth)